# Tensorboard embeddings, show sprite only on hover

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am looking for a way to display an embeddings sprite on hover, opposed to constant when using the Tensorboard Projector. The code below successfully creates a board with embeddings, and attaches the appropriate metadata and sprite to each data point. However I'm trying to visualize a dataset of over 10,000 points, so showing all images on a single screen makes it incredibly difficult to explore. Instead I'm looking for a way to show the sprite images only on hover, opposed to constant. Has anyone been able to achieve this?

```python
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Create summary writer.
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/embedding_test', sess.graph)

    # Initialize embedding_var
    sess.run(embedding_var.initializer)

    # Create Projector config
    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()

    # Add embedding visualizer
    embedding = config.embeddings.add()

    # Attach the embedding name
    embedding.tensor_name = embedding_var.name

    # Data point meta data
    embedding.metadata_path = EMBEDDING_META_PATH

    #associate data point sprite
    embedding.sprite.image_path = EMBEDDING_SPRITE_PATH

    #specify dimensions of images within sprite
    embedding.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([imgSize, imgSize])

    # Add writer and config to Projector
    projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)

    # Save the model
    saver_embed = tf.train.Saver([embedding_var])
    saver_embed.save(sess, './graphs/embedding_test/embedding_test.ckpt', 1)



writer.close()
```

As you can see, displaying all images constantly is rather overwhelming...
[image: overwhelming embedding viz]